# Visual Studio Doesn't Find All References

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When replacing a variable, I often rely on "Find All References" to actually find all references to the variable in question. Missing a reference can mean not doing the full job. Today I used find all references and it didn't work; in particular it did not find the Write reference. Do I lack in understanding of how Find All References works, or is it just a bug? I am using VS Enterprise 2019.

See screenshot. Missing reference is on Line 527:
[image]

Comment: The variable is being declared for the first time on line 527 rather than referenced, find all references will show you where that is used after it is declared. Try "Find Usages" instead

Comment: "Find usages" doesn't even exist as a feature. "Find references" should work in the described scenario. I'm also experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename a variable, class name, whatever and want to make sure all references are renamed, you can use Refactor/Rename functionality :

- Select the variable, class name, whatever you want to rename
- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> **or** Edit -> Refactor -> Rename
- Rename
- Enjoy

More infos can be found on [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ide/reference/rename?view=vs-2019)

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to answer the original question. Please delete this answer.

Comment: @alelom I suggest you to read again the question more carefully than before.

Comment: I suggest you please do the same; the title reads `Visual Studio Doesn't Find All References`, which is indeed a misbehaviour of Visual Studio in need of a solution, not `How to refactor the code to replace all references of a variable in Visual Studio`. The fact that the user reports an example where the "Find all references" feature was required for them to refactor a variable name has no relevance in appropriately answering the question, because that's not the only use case for "Find all references". This answer is only suitable for a comment.

Comment: @alelom I answer questions, not titles.
If you think the title needs to be rephrased, you can always [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63688134/edit) the question.
OP explained that when renaming a variable, they experienced a missing of references. I provided a solution to avoid that.
Now, if you really think that my answer is unsuitable for the current question, feel free to add it to the review queue by flagging it.

Comment: Let's be clear: to edit the question consistently with your answer, one would need not only to edit the title, as you propose, but also the user's screenshot, and part of the text, i.e. change entirely the content and meaning of the question . This is because the screenshot indicates the real issue, in line with the title. The user's final intent -- refactoring a variable -- has nothing to do with the fact they are experiencing a "Find All References" bug. Therefore, the question needs no edit, and this answer does not answer it. Mine is a factual statement, unlike your wrong opinion.